# Got an error with pygame and the method update

Tags: python, pygame

I'm starting to code and have been following a series of videos to create a game with pygame. However, even when I've followed everything the guy in the video said, and after checking many times mine and his code, I got  this error:
  *File "C:/Users/sdf/PycharmProjects/pygame1/pygametutorial 2/tutorail 1 template.py", line 43, in 
    all_sprites.update()
TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'*

this is the code I've programmed so far:

```
import pygame
import random

import sprites as sprites

height = 360
width = 480
FPS = 30

White = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tutorial")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill(green)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (height / 2, width / 2)


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    all_sprites.update()
    screen.fill(black)
    sprites.draw(screen)
    # after every drawing flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure what `import sprites as sprites` is, is it another file you made? Is it meant to be `import pygame.sprite.Sprite as sprite`?

```
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group
```

`Group` is a class so you need the brackets

```
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

now you are calling it and all_sprites is a group object, not referencing the class

now i changed `sprites.draw(screen)` to `all_sprites.draw(screen)` as not don't have `sprites`, and not sure what is is.

Comment: I'm not sure about the import sprite thing, I think it was pycharm who wrote it when I was messing around trying to get it to work. Also I changed what you mentioned and now there's no error but it doesn't appear the square that should be drawn, don't you know why would it be?

Comment: @MiguelArrieche That is because when you set the position in the line `self.rect.center = (height / 2, width / 2)`. You have the x and y around the wrong way, it should be `self.rect.center = (width // 2, height // 2)`